# Hacer SELECT comparando dos datos entre dos columnas en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas mi problema es que quiero comparar dos tablas y seleccionar dos datos que son iguales en las dos tablas, una vez comparado quiero que de la primera tabla me saque dos datos.
Aqui viene mi objetivo, tengo estas dos tablas:

```
operatore:                       evento:
id-name-surname                  idOp
24-Oriol-Molina                  24
```

Como veis en la dos tablas el id se repite, entonces mi idea es poder hacer en un `sql` que compare los id de las dos tablas y los que coinciden que me den el name y surname de la primera tabla.

Answer (score 7):

Lo que necesitas hacer es un **JOIN**.

> Un `JOIN` en `SQL` permite combinar las filas de dos o más tablas para
>   poder mostrar resultados de forma relacional.

En este caso necesitas usar **INNER JOIN** ya que solo quieres obtener las filas que coincidan en ambas tablas con la condicion establecida en la clausula `ON`

```
SELECT operatore.name, operatore.surname
FROM operatore
INNER JOIN evento ON operatore.id=evento.idOp;
```

Si quisieras obtener todos los datos de la tabla de la izquierda *(operatore en este caso)* ademas de los que coincidan con tu condicion de la clausula `ON` puedes usar `LEFT JOIN`. Lo mismo como puedes imaginar pero al contrario para `RIGHT JOIN`.

La siguiente imagen refleja que tipos de `JOIN` podemos usar y que datos obtenemos.
[Tipos de JOIN](https://donnierock.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/udqpd.jpg)